# ASP.NET Core Project w/ JavaScriptServices in Docker Unable to Launch Node

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

I am having issues getting a site to run properly inside of a docker container. The container builds fine and runs, however when navigating to a page it fails on loading JavaScript services.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS builder
WORKDIR /app

ADD company_cas.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/company_cas.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

COPY company_cas.pem ./
RUN npm config set cafile company_cas.pem

# Run NPM install for dependencies
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "web.dll"]
```

I am using the `microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0` base image, and npm does run so Node is installed to the best of my knowledge.

The output of the failed request is -

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
web   |       An unhandled exception has occurred: Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.
web   |       
web   |       [1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
web   |           Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
web   |           Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
web   |       
web   |       [2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
web   | System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.
web   | 
web   | [1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
web   |     Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
web   |     Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
web   | 
web   | [2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No such file or directory
```

[Full Error Stack @ Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6HfQeF87)

Is this a matter of setting a new PATH for ASP.NET to find Node? If so, any idea on what that path should be in Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I overlooked the runtime image base container.

Changed to `FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0` and now I'm good.